# Activity sent to external tenant throws error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Issue Description :
Through the app, we send activity notifications to users feed., When we send activity in the same tenant, it works, But when activity is sent to an external tenant then it throws the below error from graph API

API used :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<team_id>/sendActivityNotification
```

where -> <team_id> is team id of external tenant

Error Message :

> ERROR -> b'{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Sender of notification does not have access to the team 'fe51246f-1a2c-4af7-956f-7b124431bd31'.","innerError":{"date":"2021-10-21T09:43:55","request-id":"8c9b082c-40e6-4dea-999e-f60163060aa5","client-request-id":"8c9b082c-40e6-4dea-999e-f60163060aa5"}}}'

Please suggest ways to implement above.

Comment: Could you please try enabling multi tenant for your App registration and try it again.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?